# Can you script all indexes for a given database if there is a table defining every index?

Tags: sql-server

For some context, we've been using an updated ETL package that updates tables from an Azure server to our local DB and due to the host only allowing us to access external tables when connecting to their server, we can't access the indexes.

There is a table within their database that records every index within the database, I'm just wondering if it is at all possible to recreate the indexes using a script based on the information from this table?

The information stored within this table holds:

- Schema Name
- Table Schema
- Table Name
- Index Name
- Column Name

The idea would be to write a script that would run through each row and create an index based on the data on each row. Just not certain this is possible from my knowledge.

Comment: Side note, there is no need to have your own table to store all the indexes; the `sys` objects already have all that information.

Comment: There's `sys.indexes` but rather than blindly rebuilding everything, use [Ola Hallengren's index maintenace scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) to defragment indexes in bulk based on their actual fragmentation

Comment: I believe the comments above about system views are missing the point of the question. *"we can't access the indexes"* - they seem to be trying to recreate indexes which don't exist on their local copy at all yet

Comment: @MartinSmith that's partly the fault of the title which says `rebuild`. That's a very specific thing when talking about databases

Comment: I would say that the information held in that table is not enough to recreate the indexes with any certainty. There is no indication about included columns, clustered or non clustered, any filter predicates, key column ordering (if composite) and direction and if they use any of the more "exotic" index types (e.g. spatial, XML, full text) presumably this table does not include these

Comment: So the question then turns into can the OP query the `sys` objects, such as `sys.indexes`; if they can then they should be able to build the definition from that. If not, then it's unlikely that the table they've defined (which implies an `INDEX` is on one column, which is simply not true) won't be enough to be able to do the task.

Comment: Potentially a composite index could just have multiple rows for the same `Schema Name, Table Schema, Table Name, Index Name` but different `Column Name` but that would still leave unclear what ordering the key columns are defined in - and `asc`, `desc` ordering of the keys

Comment: The host doesn't let you query `sys.indexes`, `sys.index_columns`, etc.? What happens when you try? (And yes, I started recommending Ola when I read the original title, because it was quite misleading.)

Comment: You might also need to know if index is unique or clustered, or i dunno, spatial/ columnstored, has include columns etc. If you're using simple stuff, then yes, probably the information listed is enough (if you mean column *names* and not column *name*)